# Can't install RAID controller drivers

Tags: drivers, windows-server-2008-r2, hardware-raid

I recently had a Megaraid SAS controller die on me that had a Raid 1 and a Raid 60 setup on it.

I have the new Megaraid SAS controller installed and my RAID array imported, but obviously Windows Server is not booting because it doesn't have drivers for this new controller.

How do I install the required drivers onto this system that can't boot into Windows? It won't boot into Safe mode either.

edit: This is Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: Can you boot from the installation media into a recovery console?

Comment: Yes, I can boot from installation media.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the system up and running. I just installed a second card I had lying around and was able to boot into Windows to install the drivers for the new card.